# django compare date with date

Tags: django, date, comparison

I trying to refuse importing lines with date lesser than already imported.

```
timelimit = Operation.objects.filter(account = 3).aggregate(Max('date'))
for row in csv.reader(reencode(f), delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
  if row != []:
    if row[0]>timelimit:
      operation.date=row[0]
```

row looks like:
2012-01-12,something,0,something2

Of course comparison row[0]>timelimit is wrong - but what is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    #this will convert your string("2012-01-12") to a datetime object

    from datetime import datetime
    >>> x = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d")
    >>> x
    >>> datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 12, 0, 0)
```

And then you can convert timelimit in a datetime object too like so:

```
    timelimit = datetime(2011, 10, 10)
```

and then comparing these two is trivial:

```
    x > timelimit
```

Comment: Well, I wonder how is done assignment operation.date=row[0] (where operation.date is ModelField.DateTime

Comment: You will convert row[0] to a datetime object like in my example(x = datetime.datetime(2012,1,12,0,0) and then use .date() on the row like so: operation.date = x.date().

Comment: It doesn't work: x > timelimit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to dict

Comment: Convert timelimit to datetime object. I have it in my example above. And then you will be able to compare two datetime objects.

Comment: timelimit is a dict ;D So i have to use timelimit["date__max"]... but it is date nor datetime... How to convert?

Comment: x = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d").date() is the solution